# How to update zsh to zsh 5?

Tags: ubuntu, zsh

On Ubuntu, I used `apt-get install zsh` but it gave me `zsh 4.3.17 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)`. I want to get the latest version (5.0.5 at the moment).

What is the most stable way to get it?

I currently have oh my zsh installed with zsh 4.3.17 so will it be affected by this upgrade?

Comment: there are a lot of outdated packages in the Ubuntu repositories, the only real alternative is to compile this from the source or find a PPA that offers this package .

Comment: Ok, will this involve removing my old zsh and installing one from the source? I am concerned that there might be priority issues where my old zsh is preferred from the new one.

Comment: tipically no, when you switch shell with `chsh` you have to provide a full path to it, maybe other related libraries could possibly get in the way, but this is up to you, you should manage the compilation and the configuration of the environment around your executable .

Comment: This question belongs on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) or [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 2):

The differences between Zsh 5.X and Zsh 4.3.X are really small. The easiest way to get the latest Zsh in Debian/Ubuntu is to install `zsh-beta`. If you really must have the very latest Zsh, then you should consider compiling and installing from the source. If you never did that before, you are better off just using `zsh-beta`.